# dependency injection: Which one should be made first? attributes(fields) or dependency?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management, inject

I'm newbie in dependency injection and I have some problem.

first of all I know this:

From Christoffer Noring, Pablo Deeleman's book “Learning Angular - Second Edition”:

> As our applications grow and evolves, each one of our code entities
>   **will internally require instances of other objects, which are better
>   known as dependencies** in the world of software engineering. The action
>   of passing such dependencies to the dependent client is known as
>   injection.

Then, in some tutorial video, the instructor said we want to use Tires service in Car class so we'll inject it into Car Class and Then we'll make an attribute (tires) to save it:

```
public class Car {

    private Tires tires; 

    public Car(Tires tires){
        this.tires = tires;
    }
}
```

I'm not ok with this definition and it makes me confused because I think this definition(instructor's definition) contrast with another definition.

most of article about DI(same as About Angular) tell us that because of our needing to the instance of other class objects in our class, we have some dependency class. but in this definition, it tells that we have objects from different class that we want to inject it in your class and you should create some variables to save these values.

I think the confusing issue is the time of attribute creation. I think first we create the attribute then we have some dependency, not assume some class as dependency and then create some attributes to hold those values in host class.(client class)

can someone plz explain about that?

Comment: Dependency means "needs", and injection means "provide". So if a Car _needs_ Tires, then you provide Tires to the Car (when you create it).

Comment: And remember, these classes should really be named `CarService` and `TireService`, since they do not actually represent a car or a set of tires, where you "add" (install, mount) 4 tires (or more, or less) on a car, and then maybe later replace them. They also don't represent a car model which might specify the default brand/type of tires it comes with. Naming classes is important, and misnamed classes like these just adds to the confusion.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- , you are on point and well explained in the comment.

Comment: @Andreas Sir, I don't understand that why they do not represent a car or a set of tires and also why they don't represent a car model which might specify the default brand/type of tires it comes with :( I think everything about these two class is normal and they are same as another normal class.

Comment: @MehSar You don't normally use injection with OO / DTO / POJO classes, which are often instantiated from client requests or database records. You use injection with things like *service* classes, which are usually singletons, and are generally instantiated by an injection framework. You said it yourself *"the instructor said we want to use Tires **service** in Car class"*, implying that both classes are *service* classes, which is consistent with the use of injection.

Comment: @Andreas I've got it now. Thank You so much.

Comment: @MehSar To contrast, a `CarService` class doesn't have a `color` property. A `Car` DTO class would, and it would have a `getColor()` method. The `CarService` class has no properties (it may have fields for internal use only), but it may have methods like `Car buildCar(Color)`, or `Car getCar(String tag)` to load `Car` values from a database for a car with that license plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think first we create the attribute

I think you might be confusing OOP concepts with injection.

You `Car` *service* class (nothing to do with OOP), need access to the `Tires` *service* class, so the `Car` instance expects a `Tires` instance to be injected during construction, and it needs to save that for later use, so it stores the reference in a *field* (not attribute<sup>1</sup>).

The field is defined (declared, "created") when we decide that we need to save the injected reference for later.

I guess you could say we define ("create") the field when we *realize* we need a reference to the `Tire` service, and then go add it as a dependency to the constructor, but that's just semantic about when you write the code, i.e. whether you look ahead and create the dependency before you write the code that needs it, or you create the dependencies on-the-fly as you write the code.

<sup>*1) The word "attribute" is used when we have getter (and setter) methods for an external class to use. An injected reference, for internal use only, is not considered to be a "attribute" of the class.*</sup>

Comment: *You **Car service** class , need access to the **Tire service** class, so it expects a Tires instance to be injected during construction* ...... so who creates the Tire instances, Tire service class??

Comment: @VishwaRatna Missed an `s`. Fixed and clarified. Not my fault they don't have `Service` in the class names. See [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961903/dependency-injection-which-one-should-be-made-first-attributesfields-or-depe/60962022#comment107853901_60961903).